# Finding out if a sequence of digits is a "numpad path"

Tags: probability

I noticed that several of my old credit cards have verification codes which have an interesting property which I'll call "numpathable".

A *numpad* is a graph that looks like this:

```
7 - 8 - 9
|   |   |
4 - 5 - 6
|   |   |
1 - 2 - 3
```

A number $n$ is a *numpad path* (or *numpath*, if you like) if its digits can be produced by moving along the edges of this graph, with at most one edge in between consecutive digits in $n$.

For example, $4556$ is a numpad path, as are $1$, $12$, and $123$ and $12321$. $987456321$ is the largest number that's a numpad path without repeating any digits.

However $4553$ isn't a numpad path, because you must traverse more than one edge between $5$ and $3$. $1234$ is also not a numpad path for the same reason. Similarly, any number containing $0$ isn't a numpad path since $0$ doesn't appear on this graph.

**Q: What is the probability $P(d)$ that a random $d$-digit number ($d > 0$) is a numpad path?** (Clearly, all 1 digit-numbers except 0 are numpad paths, so $P(1) = 0.9$.)

---

**Edit:** I previously called these "numpad tours", but a commenter pointed out that tours typically touch *every* node in a graph, so I've renamed it to *numpad paths*.

Comment: Simplifications to the problem: 1) Ignore numbers that have any zeros as digits. You can multiply by $1-(9/10)^d$ later. 2) The problem then reduces to finding the number of paths of length $=d$ in your graph (if you do not allow the same digit to appear in adjacent positions). If you allow consecutive repetitions of a digit, then you need to count paths of length $\le d$ weighted by the different ways you can repeat digits to get to a $d$-digit number.

Comment: I would do it recursively.  You'll have to distinguish between strings according to the nature of the last digit. Some digits have $2-$ neighbors, some have $3$ and  five has $4$, and that dictates how many options you have for the next move.

Comment: Just as a side note, the word *tour* here may be misleading. A knight's tour, for instance, will touch every square, and I would expect a numpad tour to touch every key. I'm sorry for this essentially useless comment because it's an interesting question!

Comment: This is a very interesting question. +1 from me.

Comment: @dbx You're right, that's confusing. I renamed these to _numpad paths_ in accordance with the more conventional terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursion approach.
Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of numpad tours of length $n$, ending with digit $k$. Let
$$\mathbf{f}_n:=(f(n,1),f(n,2),f(n,3),f(n,4),f(n,5),f(n,6),f(n,7),f(n,8),f(n,9))^T$$
Thus $\mathbf{f}_{n+1}=A\mathbf{f}_n$ where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
The desired value is then $\frac{1}{10^{d-1}\cdot 9}(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)A^{d-1}(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)^T$.

Then we perform Jordan decomposition of $A=SJS^{-1}$ (WA, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%7D)) to get $A^n=SJ^nS^{-1}$ (where $n=d-1$) and finally compute (see [here](https://tio.run/##hZFNT4QwEIbv/Io5UqTVctS4R5M9mJjskWBCXIxNoFlp12hIfzvCttUBWwwv/ZpnPjrtav3WdLUWL/U4qtv7YeA53Fw0LajduImbHAZrmA8P770uiwoT8@SOHWtxqx8Hjr19VLoOG8EXGVDewtdtVcTCohWuaaN0yqNeGy3hfkRRcW85poy5S45y0f61FpkixrD91zgp5UChyFxR5FluwZ4P02t0gw6glr76Q4fRIB1FPY3vObf4qRdSlw/ntj2I7tSK168ySTNQLD1KuGYwSKC76TUIe6x1Lz738qPpVZMqAhlJ5sdZfcawizNhDi1VxSbO5P/8JqmqcfwG)) the fraction numerator of $$\frac14(2 + (17 - 12\sqrt{2})(1 - 2\sqrt{2})^n + (1 + 2\sqrt{2})^n(17 + 12\sqrt{2})).$$

Comment: Great answer, and thank you for also providing working code that let me experiment a bit. I was surprised this had a closed-form solution, but it's very clear now that it should.